# Invalid input data in postman!! Postman test API asp.net core

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, postman

[image]

I want to test API in postman, but I receive invalid input. It's code httPost in asp.net core

[image]

It's in PostMan. Please help me!

Comment: It may be because your `GetTopInfo` method is abnormal. Can you share this method? You can also delete your `try` and `catch` statements, so you can see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public IActionResult GetTopInfor([FromBody] JObject p)

In your action method, we can find that it accepts a `JObject` type parameter.

Firstly, please note that `JObject` is a class that belongs to `Newtonsoft.Json`, since .NET Core 3, [the default JSON serializer for ASP.NET Core is now System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#fast-built-in-json-support).

To make it can handle `JObject` parameter well, please check if you add Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) support by calling `AddNewtonsoftJson`, for more information, please check following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project

Besides, please debug your code to trace the actual value of `p` and check if any exception is thrown while you invoke your custom service `_orderService.GetTopInfor(row)`.

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my problem. I have fixed it! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***ex.Message.ToString()*** instead of ***GetErrorMsg(6)***.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `JObject`, you get the value using `GetValue()` method.
try this :

```
row = Int32.Parse(p.GetValue("row").ToString());
```

also, your code is a bit all over the place. you should rearrange it to make it more readable.